# How do I change an object variable through a non-node JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

**Hi**.
Let's start off by saying that I have an Express server that sends an html website to the browser.

On that server, I also have a `db.js` file which contains an Object variable inside of it:

```
const settings =  {
    // Some example settings here:
    ok: true,
    cost: 50,
    value = "Hello, World!"
};

module.exports = settings;
```

and I can access it with just:

```
// First, requiring the file:
const file = require("./db.js");

// Then accessing it.
console.log(file.settings.ok)
```

and this works just fine, **as long as it's in the server file.**

> *How can I access this value in a pure javascript file that is on an html page (`<script></script>`) and doesn't have the require() function or doesn't recognize the `module.exports` function in the `db.js` file?*

Attempts at making it work:

- Using it just normal, like a node.js file (which it isn't) > require() method is unresolved, *expected*.
- Using the [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/) library > failed due to the website not recognizing what the `module.exports` is. *(required for exporting the object from the db.js file)*.

Possible fixes, that I don't necessarily know how to do:

- Sending this variable to the HTML file through the Express file
- Somehow adding the required node.js syntax to the html javascript file

If you are missing any information about my situation, I'm very welcome to supply it to you, just comment.

> Edit: **I DO** need to change the values, so `read only` won't cut it.

Comment: You can make the data in that object available on the client side easily, but you cannot *change* the data in the serverside object without node.js.

Comment: Instead of RequireJS, use a module loader that supports the CommonJS format. Or just use a tranpiler. Or alternatively, add an API endpoint to your server that just responds with the `file.settings` as json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit your data to the server in order to modify the `ok` value.

The server can run with `node server.js`, it will run on http://localhost:3001.

In this example, submitting the form will redirect to the html rendered by the server, and display the modified value.

```js
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const settings = require('./db');

const PORT = 3001;

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/modify', (req, res) => {
    const { body } = req;
    settings.ok = body.ok;
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.send(`<h2>Value ok is now set to: ${settings.ok}</h2>`);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('./index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at ${PORT}`);
});
```

And your client can post a simple form to that server. This is index.html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h1>Super app</h1>
    <form id="my-form" action="http://localhost:3001/modify" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="ok"></input>
    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented you can't modify the value *on the server* without writing and calling some server-side code, but if all you need to do is pass the file to the browser and read and modify its values within the browser context, then that's possible. @Bergi has a few options for you there, I have one more:

If you wish to share code modules between client and server, I highly recommend adopting the newer "ES6 modules" syntax. So your code would look like:

```js
// settings.js
export const settings =  {
    // Some example settings here:
    ok: true,
    cost: 50,
    value = "Hello, World!"
};
```

Then where you want to use or modify the settings:

```js
// app.js
import { settings } from "./settings.js"

settings.value = "to the Moon"
```

This is natively supported by all modern ("evergreen") browsers without any need for a transpiler, by using the `type="module"` attribute on the  tag like:

```html
<script src="app.js" type="module" />
```

There is an excellent NPM package called `esm` which adds really good support for it in Node too (https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm).

This will make your code more future-proof than using "legacy" module loaders like RequireJS.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Your answer is great, but I need to modify the server-side data, sadly. It is still helpful though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access server JS files in a browser, this would be a huge security risk.

Since you're using Express, you can just create a route that returns a JSON object (application/json) with the settings, then use `fetch` to get the contents of that.

```js
async function getSettings() {
  const res = await fetch('/settings');
  const json = await res.json();
  // json is your settings
}
```